# Forms Authentication IsAuthenticated Not Working External Link

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication

- I log in to website (tab 1) and connect to page that requires
  authentication.
- I then create myself a link in word (can be any link
  from anywhere) but crucially linked to same default browser that
  retains the login details.
- Clicking the link opens a new tab (tab 2)
  to same said website BUT it asks for login details!

Back end code to webpage has `if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) then` REDIRECT

I don't understand, if user is in tab 1 logged in and external link opens tab 2 in Chrome, why does it think the user is logged out... I probably should know why but I'm too old to spend years finding out why.

Hope someone can help.

[UPDATE]
Debugging the code it appears the load event is loading twice. The first time Chrome's tab isn't open and IsAuthenticated is false, then 2nd time IsAuthenticated = true but it's too late as I have already actioned on the first call!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are cookies unrecognized when a link is clicked from an external source (i.e. Excel, Word, etc...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653626/why-are-cookies-unrecognized-when-a-link-is-clicked-from-an-external-source-i-e)

Comment: The comment was generated automatically because I voted to mark the question as a duplicate in the system, which will add a more prominent link, and make it clearer in search results that the answers are on that page not this one. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the problem. MS Outlook and MS Word appear to be the issue. Thanks to this I was able to respond accordingly:
[Why are cookies unrecognized when a link is clicked from an external source (i.e. Excel, Word, etc...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653626/why-are-cookies-unrecognized-when-a-link-is-clicked-from-an-external-source-i-e)

Answer (score 0):

More and more browsers are treating each tab as a separate instance instead of a tab in a single instance. For Chrome, you can read this URL: http://www.howtogeek.com/124218/why-does-chrome-have-so-many-open-processes/