# Excel links to JIRA issues forcing re-authentication

Tags: excel, jira, excel-2013

## Situation

Attempting to launch a JIRA issue hyperlink from Excel 2013 drives the user to a login page for JIRA which is unexpected as the user has an active login session.

Example link format --> `https://<subdomain>.atlassian.net/browse/<proj-#>`

Even if the user logs in the first time, checks the box for "Keep me logged in" the user still must repeat this the next time a JIRA link from Excel is selected.

The URL appends the parameter `&permission-violation=true`

## Attempts to Debug

1. Copy the link to clipboard and paste directly in browser URL bar.  This method does not generate the permission violation.  User can go directly to issue without logging in again.
2. Attempt the link in a different Office 2013 application.  Using the same link from a MS Outlook 2013 email does not generate the permission violation.
3. Browse the JIRA administration page for solutions.  Could not find any such option to configure.
4. Tested with both Firefox and Chrome set as the default browser.  Issue persists for each.

Any suggestions to fix this?  The behavior is very frustrating to our end users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are cookies unrecognized when a link is clicked from an external source (i.e. Excel, Word, etc...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653626/why-are-cookies-unrecognized-when-a-link-is-clicked-from-an-external-source-i-e)

Answer (score 1):

**The Problem**

According to StackOverflow user [myroslav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38592/myroslav), certain versions of Excel are first attempting to fetch the webpage using a Microsoft DLL that does not know about your browser's cookies (i.e. your login session). Here's an excerpt of his answer:

> If session cookie protects website Hlink naturally is being redirected
>   to login page and having reached HTML page and not able to
>   "understand" it opens it in external browser. Note that it opens not
>   original URL (expected behavior) but the result of redirect, even if
>   it was 302 redirect.

His full answer can be read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2736814).

**The Solution**

At this time, Microsoft has recommended that companies with single sign-on sites like Atlassian's should [address the issue on their end](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/899927). Such a fix is [low on Atlassian's priority list](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-41879). In the meantime, we are left to either accept Microsoft's solution - modify the registry [as myroslav instructs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2736814) and accept a loss of Excel functionality - or modify our URL to something that doesn't require single sign-on user validation.

**The Workaround**

I'm using Excel 2016 and Chrome. [Taliesin's workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32467265/4686951), elsewhere on this page, did not work for me, but might work for some. Here's a next-best-thing workaround that *did* work:

```
HYPERLINK("https://<subdomain>.atlassian.net/issues/?jql=id%20in%20("&<cell>&")", "link")
```

Replace `<subdomain>` with your Atlassian subdomain, and `<cell>` with the cell containing your JIRA issue key.

This URL variant opens a search query for issues matching the given key. It doesn't take you directly to the issue, but it at least offers a convenient link to get where you want to go, which is at least better than entering your credentials on the login page *again*.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the browser and login to JIRA by selecting keep me signed in

Comment: This test was performed initially.  Does not address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to resolve the issue: https://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/14287?r=40540

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\"YOUR OFFICE VERSION"\Common\Internet]
"ForceShellExecute"=dword:00000001

Comment: I think you are on the right track.  Unfortunately, that fix doesn't appear to work in Office 2013 per the last comment in the forum post.  I checked myself and "Internet" does not exist in that folder path for this version.

Comment: Did you try to create it?

Comment: I did yes.  Sadly, this fix does not work using Office 2013.

Comment: maybe change hyperlink address from `http://yoursite.com` to `start http://yoursite.com` - to make excel open web page with program start?

Comment: Good idea.  Excel does not like this though...  
  
Address entered in context option or thru VBA:
`start https://yoursite.com`
What the link actually shows or behaves as:
`<filepathtoexcelfile>\start%20https://yoursite.com`

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround

Ok.  So I have discovered a workaround.  Note this will correct the issue in an indirect way by leveraging JIRA's own link correction behavior.  Essentially, you can bypass the security issue by providing JIRA with an incorrectly structured URL.  JIRA will then fix the URL and redirect you to the correct page.

Here is the structure `https://<subdomain>.atlassian.net/browse/<proj-#>` + `/`

Note the last ***forward slash***.  This does not belong in the URL construction but when used will establish the redirect and thereby bypass the security violation.

If you already have your hyperlinks in a JIRA file you can easily update those in batch by using this simple VBA code subroutine.

```vb
Sub AppendJiraLinks()

Dim c As Range
Dim i As Integer

For Each c In Selection.Cells

    If c.Hyperlinks.Count >= 1 Then
        For i = 1 To c.Hyperlinks.Count
            c.Hyperlinks(i).Address = c.Hyperlinks(i).Address & "/"
        Next i
    End If

Next c

End Sub
```

Note this code could be enhanced but works fine for my purposes.